# Folder as website root

Tags: .htaccess, indexing, web, directory

Today I started building a website and I was wondering if I can do this:

example.com/aco | ROOT/acp

example.com/ucp | ROOT/ucp

example.com/ | ROOT/home

so that if you browse example.com/ it will use example.com/home/index.html and when you go to example.com/shop.html it will use example.com/home/shop.html

So how to foward the example.com/ to a folder but the folder doesn't show up in the url. 
I think this need to be done by .htaccess but how

Answer (score 0):

Typically http servers are configured such that requests to `http(s)://example.com/` are internally rewritten to use a directory index. This again can be configured inside the http servers main configuration to have a prioritized set of options (files) to chose from.

This means that you do not have to make any manual rewriting as long as you obey typical naming conventions like index.html or index.php for the directory index.

However you should consider if it really is such a good idea to closely bind your navigation hierarchy to some file system hierarchy. Usually one does *not* want such thing. Instead create a compact request router which loads whatever routine is required to process the current request. This gives you much more freedom, is more robust and reveals less about your internal setup.

Comment: So set it to a folder with the index.php init is not possible?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by that question. What do you mean by "set it"?